# Parsing timestamp containing special characters (quotes)

Tags: c#, .net

So, the other day I ran into a problem when trying to parse a timestamp which was wrapped in quotes, it looked like this in the file I was reading:

```
"2018-04-09"
```

A C# string with this content:

```
var dt = "\"2018-04-09\""
```

I wanted to use DateTime.TryParseExact() to convert the string into a .net DateTime object, without stripping the chars from the string (don't ask why, it's not relevant), but finding a working format string turned out to be tricky.

I read the docs. I googled. Searched StackOverflow. No success.

What format would allow me to parse this timestamp to a DateTime object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - the solution, handed to me by a colleague:

```
var format = "\\\"yyyy-MM-dd\\\"";
```

If I understand this correctly, the format string is expected to contain a \ which is later resolved to escape the " inside ParseExact(). The first \ escapes the second, the third escapes ", leading to the character sequence \" as part of the format string which is then processed somewhere down the line.

The following works:

```
var dts = "\"2018-04-09\"";
var format = "\\\"yyyy-MM-dd\\\"";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dts, format, null);
```

I hope this helps someone!